# ASP.Net 4.5 OAuth fails with a 400 response, out of the box

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, visual-studio-2012

I fired up VS 2012 and created a new website with the oAuth templates and created an application with Facebook to test it out. I modified the AuthConfig.cs to contain the app id and app secret, but my login test is returning a 400 response, presumably from Facebook's server.

Here is my app configuration on Facebook: 
[image]

Here is the line upon which the 400 response occurs:

```
var authResult = OpenAuth.VerifyAuthentication(redirectUrl);
```

Like I said, I've modified the two lines in AuthConfig.cs, but nothing else.

Thoughts?

Comment: HTTP 400 is Bad Request, was there any additional info in an Inner Exception? Have you traced it in fiddler or used System.Diagnostics to dump the request/response to a log file? Check this site for a step by step guide to double check that everything thats needed to be configured has been done - note the localhost:portnumber bullet points if you're running locally http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx.

Comment: Inner exception is null, and the 400 request doesn't show up in the Fiddler stack...I suspect this is because it's happening inside the IIS Express process...

Comment: However...I was able to check the Response property of the WebException, and it indicates "Error validating client secret" in one of the headers, so I've got a little more to go on now.

Answer (score 1):

Urg...I had a leading space in the app secret. This can happen when you copy and paste directly from the page. Anyhow, I removed the space, and away it went.